# React - Is it a best practice to use Loader in the main Routes for the API call

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

AIM: To fetch an api on the web application load on the project level. Because, the application in dependent on this api call. So, If there a place where I can call an api on project level. Please suggest that solution as well.

Sample code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    APICall();
  },[])

  if (isLoading) { // Getting the loader state from 
    //API call
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return <Routes>
    <Route element={<HomePage />} path="/">
  </Routes>;
}
```

Doubt:
Is this best practice to call an API on the mainroutes and make the spinner load till the API
is fetched or else will this cause any side effect. If possible please suggest an alternate solution for this issue.

Comment: No, it's not the best way to do that you can call API on all different components and set a centralized loader in the routes page.

Comment: The best practice is subjective - it all depends on your application functionalities, the complexity of your application, and your application architecture. If I were you, if the application is 'simple' enough, I would do as you did here. But if it were a complex application, I would do like Meet Majevadiya said (set a centralized loader, while I dispatch API calls in each components).

Comment: @Nicholas/@Meet Majevadiya - Then can I use higher order component to achive this without duplicating the code?

Comment: Of course it is possible. You can create something like `WithAPICall({ url, onSuccess, onFailure })` higher order component for example.

Answer (score 2):

There're many solutions. But mostly it depends on your project complexity. For really simple projects it's not ideal, but it's okay to make as you did. But I would highly recommend letting the fetch responsibility to your components that really need those data - so you should think about breaking your components

1. One feature that it's worthy to take a look at is ["loader"](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader#loader) function from react-router, which is a great feature that you could be using.
   With this feature you ensure that you're providing the correct fetched data for each of your routes.
2. You could be using react-query library, because it's a better alternative for useEffect, on the performance level. With ["react-query"](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/) you fetch data as soon as rendering starts so you don’t have to wait until react loads the entire component
3. For really complex projects with many API calls, you could use ["redux-sagas"](https://redux-saga.js.org/)
4. Create a wrapper component that encapsulate this API call. For example, you have 2 types of pages in your application - protected and unprotected routes. You could create a component that receives another Component as prop and are called: `ProtectedRoutes` which returns 2 components conditionally - `UnProtectedPage` and `Component`.